# Google timeline custom tooltip (bug shift)

Tags: tooltip, timeline

I am a customized tooltip.
But now, when you change the filter range desynchronizes tooltip with the block.
Somebody sees the cause of the bug ?

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/gsv48wqg/`
```

Comment: Share the code for reference.

Comment: i have attached link to jsfiddle